# promisify the acquireTokenWithClientCredentials function from adal-node

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I would like to authenticate against Azure from my Node backend. The `acquireTokenWithClientCredentials` helps me out. Unfortunately I have to pass in a callback but I would like to await it and return a Promise with the new fetched token.

First I will show my working code using a callback

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationsService {
    private session: TokenResponse;

    private authenticationContext: AuthenticationContext;

    // -- setup the AuthenticationContext and configurations in the constructor --

    getSession(sessionCallback: Function): void {
        if (!this.session || this.session.expiresOn < new Date()) {
            this.authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(resource, clientId, clientSecret, (error: Error, tokenResponse: TokenResponse) => {
                if (error) {
                    throw error;
                }

                this.session = tokenResponse;
                sessionCallback(this.session);
            });
        } else {
            sessionCallback(this.session);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to note that I only fetch a new session if the current one has expired. I would like to await that callback and return a Promise instead. Other functions requesting the session don't have to deal with callbacks then. So my updated code should look like

```
async getSession(): Promise<TokenResponse> {
    if (!this.session || this.session.expiresOn < new Date()) {
        try {
            this.session = await this.authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(resource, clientId, clientSecret);
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }

    return this.session;
}
```

Is there a way I can await the `acquireTokenWithClientCredentials` function and don't have to use a callback?

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it working with this code. Basically I'm just returning a new promise

```
async getSession(): Promise<TokenResponse> {
    if (!this.session || this.session.expiresOn < new Date()) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(resource, clientId, clientSecret, (error: Error, tokenResponse: TokenResponse) => {
                if (error) {
                    return reject(error);
                }

                this.session = tokenResponse;
                return resolve(this.session);
            });
        });
    }

    return this.session;
}
```

Please let me know if this can be simplified :)